# Fetch date value using javascript in Cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I want to fetch date value in javascript and I am using cakephp default date function.
Problem is it shows 3(day-month-year) different dropdown and .change execute on each dropdown but I want to fetch complete date (like 20-11-2012).
I want to fetch date value before submit as i want to apply validations on it.

I think I forgot to mention that I dont want to use "date picker".[image]

Comment: Ok, you don't want date picker and default cake dropdown for date. So, what you want?

Comment: i said i'm using cake default and i dont wish to use date picker. i never said i donot want default cake dropdown.

Comment: It is not clear to me which "cake default date function" you are using? Are you trying to use a date inside JavaScript or have it displayed on page as an input field?

Comment: It would be best if you posted the code segments you are using.

Comment: @VanjaD. **echo $form->input('dateSelectBoxes', array('type'=>'date'));**
This is how the given drop-downs in screen-shot are generated

Comment: When in doubt, check the generated source of the form (or inspect it with a developer tool (Firebug)) to see what's the generated ID or class of the HTML elements or use the 'id'/'class' param in the options of Form::input.

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize Cake's naming conventions for Form elements.

For instance, if you call `$this->input('Model.field', array('type'=>'date'))` in the view, the generated html selectboxes have these ids: `#ModelFieldMonth, #ModelFieldDay, #ModelFieldYear`.

So code to get the full date in JS:

```
var date = $('#ModelFieldYear').val() + '-' + $('#ModelFieldMonth').val() + '-' + $('#ModelFieldDay').val();
```

Comment: +1 for selectbox ids.. ;) I guess this was what @navin was looking for, at least this solved my problem.